# how to change the structure of already developed android project?

Tags: android, android-mvp, android-mvvm

I am just a beginner and at the time of developing i was blind about following an architecture, but now I've come across many awesome architecture and frameworks out there which i can follow to make code clean and easy to maintain.. so I have 3 questions

1) Is it a wise thing to change already developed project to follow a particular structure or framework like MVP and MVVM.

2) If yes for first question, how much time does it take (I know it depends on the project size but still rough estimation)

3) Which architecture would be better suitable to change the structure. (I've already gone through many documents and stack overflow questions of comparison. But here i want to change the whole structure. so which one would be best for this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It'd be better if you stick to one particular architecture from the beginning of developing your application. It's gonna be a tiresome job if you wanna change the architecture, you're gonna have to do it from scratch.

2) It'd probably take as much as time as you did for creating you application with mvc architecture I guess.

3) I'd go for MVP architecture. It's the better alternative to MVVM if you're planning to change from MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of code you have written is not very large , you can certainly change the structure.
MVP helps you to seperate views from logic and i have found using it to be very helpful when it comes to adding new logic , methods or modifying existing code.